# How to factorize this 3rd order polynomial with maple

Tags: symbolic-math, maple, computer-algebra-systems

There is some behavior of maple, that I do not understand. Say I want to factorize the polynomial `1-z-z^3`, so I compute its roots using

```
z0 := solve(1-z-z^3=0,z);
```

which gives (just for completeness...)

```
z0 := 1/6*(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)-2/(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3), -1/12*(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)+1/(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)+1/2*I*3^(1/2)*(1/6*(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)+2/(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)), -1/12*(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)+1/(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)-1/2*I*3^(1/2)*(1/6*(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)+2/(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3))
```

Now if I try to factor out the first root,

```
factor(1-z-z^3,z0[1]);
```

i get

```
Error, (in factor) 2nd argument, 1/6*(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3)-2/(108+12*93^(1/2))^(1/3), 
is not a valid algebraic extension
```

What does this mean? Is this a bug, or is the expression for `z0[1]` just too complicated? If the second is true, what is a better practice for factorizing polynomials of order, say, 3 to 4?

Comment: After I wrote the answer below, a friend mentioned you might just want to see the result of the division. Is that the case? If so, try: `evala((1-z-z^3)/z0[1])`.

Comment: I wonder whether by "factor out the first root" he means that he wants to deflate by the `z-z0[1]` factor, given that `1-z-z^3=(z-z0[1])*(z-z0[2])*(z-z0[3])` when fully expanded and simplified (by radnormal or evala/Normal, say). So, rather than divide by `z0[1]` he may wish to divide by `z-z0[1]`. Or use `evala(Divide(1-z-z^3,z-z0[1],'q'))` where `q` is thus assigned by side-effect the quotient which should equal `(z-z0[2])*(z-z0[3])` under normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Maple wants, specifically, a `RootOf` or rational power expression, or set of them, as its second argument. So for example,

```
factor(x^2-2, 1+sqrt(2))
```

will not work, whereas

```
factor(x^2-2, sqrt(2))
```

does. Similarly, in your example, you'll want to extract the rational powers from the expression that you solved for. You can do that as follows:

```
factor(1-z-z^3, indets(z0[1], anything^And(rational, Non(integer))))
```

or maybe a little less contrived:

```
with_rootof := convert(z0[1], RootOf);
factor(1-z-z^3, indets(with_rootof, specfunc(RootOf)));
```

Comment: The answer produced by your code is interesting, but seems more convoluted (with nested **RootOf**s) than it needs to be. Do you have any problem with the simpler (and simpler to get) answer provided by **factor(1-z-z^3, RootOf(1-z-z^3))**, assuming that we already know that the polynomial is irreducible over *Q*?   Unrelated comment: The syntax **specfunc(RootOf)** is a recent (and welcome) innovation. Older Maple will need **specfunc(anything, RootOf)**.

Comment: No problem whatsoever with it, @CarlLove. I had somehow acquired the idea that the user wanted the answer expressed in terms of the roots he received from `solve`, but that's not explicitly mentioned in the question at all.